# Query not doing index seek or scan

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, rdbms

I am fairly new to Indexes. I have table following table [FORUM1]

```
    [msg_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [cat_id] [int] NULL,
    [msg_title] [nvarchar](255) NULL
```

And have created a non clustered index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX catindex ON forum1(cat_id)
```

Now when i run this simple query, i can see index is not being used

```
SELECT msg_title FROM forum1 where cat_id=4
```

Index only gets called if i create CI and include the MSG_TITLE fld. But the issue is that i have to run many more similar queries on actually table like date=something, userid=20, status=1. So including columns in every index doesn't good to me .

[image: Execution plan screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `msg_title` is not contained in the index -> any value found in the non-clustered index will need a **key lookup** into the actual data pages, which is an **expensive operation** - so therefore, most likely, a table scan is quicker. Plus: the "table scan" indicates you have a heap - a table without a clustered index - which is a bad thing (most of the time) to begin with. Why don't you have a clustered index?

You can fix this by e.g. **including** the `msg_title` in your index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX catindex 
ON forum1(cat_id) INCLUDE(msg_title)
```

and now, I'm pretty sure, SQL Server will use that index (since it can find all the data needed for the query in the index structure - the index is said to be a **covering index**). The benefit here is: the extra column is only *included* in the leaf level of the index, so it makes the index only minimally bigger. Yet, it can lead to the index being used just all that more often. Well worth it!

Comment: Thanks.. So does that mean we need to have "COVERING Index" for an index to scan/seek .. I mean is that compulsory ??

Comment: @surajjain - No, the fact that right now the optimizer decided to use a table scan instead of an index seek or an index scan, is that for your current selection (`cat_id=4`), the nested loop that it needs to do on the rows that are selected would perform worst than the table scan. If you use a more selective filter (i.e. a value for  cat_id that returns fewer rows) then it will most likely use the index anyway (without the index being a covering index)

Comment: It's not compulsory - but highly effective. In my systems, I've discovered that a great many non-clustered indexes aren't being used at all - unless they become covering indexes. The cost of the key lookup - finding something in your nonclustered index, then going to the clustered index (or heap in your case) to find the whole data page - is very high - most developers underestimate that cost.